# Kotlin: Delegate override function how to make work with lambda and function parens

Tags: kotlin, delegates, extension-methods, kotlin-logging

I am trying to override the `error()` method of `kotlin-logging`.

The following code is close to what I want, but I don’t understand a few things (I’m new to Kotlin).

Example code:

```kotlin
import mu.KLogger
import mu.KotlinLogging

open class BgrLogging(
    private val delegate: KLogger
) : KLogger by delegate {
    override fun error(msg: () -> Any?) {
        delegate.error("$msg xxxx")
    }
}

fun KLogger.toBgrLogging() = BgrLogging(this)

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}.toBgrLogging()
```

I would like to be able to call my overridden `error()` method like so:

```kotlin
logger.error("should override error")
// Output: should override error
```

… unfortunately, this appears to skip my override and calls the original `error()` in `kotlin-logging`.

If I use a lambda:

```kotlin
logger.error{ "should override error" }
// Output: () -> kotlin.Any? xxxx
```

It calls my override (yay!), but the output is not what I want.

### Observation

When I call `kotlin-logging` directly (no overrides), both of these seem to work as I would expect:

```kotlin
logger.error("foo1")
logger.error{ "foo1" }
```

It outputs the string as it was passed.

### Question

Is it possible to get both `logger.error("xxxx")` and `logger.error{ "xxxx" }` to call my overridden function? I’d like both invocations to output the actual string, and not `() -> kotlin.Any?`.

```
Java 17
Kotlin Compiler Version: 1.6.10
kotlin-logging 1.5.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logger.error("should override error")
```

does not call your overridden `error` because it has the signature `(String) -> Unit` whereas you only override the error with signature `(() -> Any?) -> Unit`. In Kotlin's model, overloaded functions are completely separate from one another.

If you want to override `error` when called on strings you will have to override that method as well.

Comment: Wow, that was an an easy fix! I just had to add `override fun error(msg: String) { ... }` and it works. Thank you!